# React Native Navigation V5 Stack , BottomTab and Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I used Bottom, Stack and Drawer Navigation in My Project.

I need to Navigate to Events Page Without Adding to Bottom Navigator.

My problem:

If i need to navigate One Component in to another Component With out Adding the Component to Bottom Navigator there is two file's Code given here If need to navigate to Events Page I can't Navigate if i declare the Events Component inside  the <Tab.Navigator> Component i can navigate to Events Compnents. But It's show also in Bottom Tab Navigator I don't want this Component in Bottom Navigator.

App.js

````
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import {DrawerContent} from './Screens/DrawerContent';
    import {Events} from './Screens/Events'
    import MainTabScreen from './Screens/Bottomtab'
    
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    
    
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={MainTabScreen} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });```
    
    BottomTab Screen.js
    
        enter code here
    
    ```
    import React from "react";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
    import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
    
    import Home from "./HomeScreen";
    import About from "./AboutUs";
    import Contact from "./ContactUs";
    import Test from "./Test";
    import Events from "./Events";
    
    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
    const AboutStack = createStackNavigator();
    const ContactStack = createStackNavigator();
    const TestStack = createStackNavigator();
    const EventsStack = createStackNavigator();
    
    const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
    
    const MainTabScreen = () => (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        activeColor="#fff"
        //   style={{ backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeStackScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarColor: "#009387",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <Icon name="ios-home" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="ContactUs"
          component={ContactStackScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Notifications",
            tabBarColor: "#1f65ff",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <Icon name="ios-notifications" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="About"
          component={AboutStackScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Profile",
            tabBarColor: "#694fad",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <Icon name="ios-person" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Test"
          component={TestStackScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Search",
            tabBarColor: "#d02860",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <Icon name="ios-aperture" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
    
        {/* <Tab.Screen
          name="Events"
          component={EventsStackScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Search",
            tabBarColor: "#d02860",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <Icon name="ios-aperture" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        /> */}
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
    export default MainTabScreen;
    
    const HomeStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
      <HomeStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#009387",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      >
        <HomeStack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{
            title: "Home",
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button
                name="ios-menu"
                size={25}
                backgroundColor="#009387"
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              ></Icon.Button>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </HomeStack.Navigator>
    );
    
    const ContactStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
      <ContactStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#1f65ff",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      >
        <ContactStack.Screen
          name="ContactUs"
          component={Contact}
          options={{
            title: "ContactUs",
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button
                name="ios-menu"
                size={25}
                backgroundColor="#1f65ff"
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              ></Icon.Button>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </ContactStack.Navigator>
    );
    const AboutStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
      <AboutStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#694fad",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      >
        <AboutStack.Screen
          name="About"
          component={About}
          options={{
            title: "AboutUs",
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button
                name="ios-menu"
                size={25}
                backgroundColor="#694fad"
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              ></Icon.Button>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </AboutStack.Navigator>
    );
    const TestStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
      <TestStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#d02860",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      >
        <TestStack.Screen
          name="Test"
          component={Test}
          options={{
            title: "Test",
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button
                name="ios-menu"
                size={25}
                backgroundColor="#d02860"
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              ></Icon.Button>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </TestStack.Navigator>
    );
    const EventsStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
      <EventsStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#d02860",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      >
        <EventsStack.Screen
          name="Events"
          component={Events}
          options={{
            title: "Events",
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button
                name="ios-menu"
                size={25}
                backgroundColor="#d02860"
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              ></Icon.Button>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </EventsStack.Navigator>
    );
````

There is two file's Code given here If need to navigate to Events Page I can't Navigate if i declare the Events Component inside  the <Tab.Navigator> Component i can navigate to Events Compnents.But It's show also in Bottom Tab Navigator I don't want this Component in Bottom Navigator.

I need call the EventsStackScreen With Out Adding into <Tab.Navigator>